# iPad crash after 20 minutes downloading data to Core Data model

Tags: ios, core-data, memory, crash, automatic-ref-counting

I'm experiencing a crash on my iPad which I think is related to my app just running out of memory, however I can't seem to glean any information about the crash itself in order to resolve it.  The app uses ARC.

The app spends about 20 minutes downloading data from our server and populating a Core Data model.  Around the 20 minutes mark, the app crashes.

The device isn't running out of space - in fact the downloaded content takes up just a hundred megabytes.  I'm using only a single managed context object (nb. I'm not saving the context until the entire data set has downloaded).

When I run in debug with an exception breakpoint enabled, I app just crashes without breaking and without displaying any type of warning or error.

Any advice on how to track down the problem?  From the crash log below, does it look like the app is just running out of memory, or might it be

Here's the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: A619465F-2E85-4BBC-BBE7-2330D4700FB8
CrashReporter Key:   6fa0c5a4f6cbeaf7a98e6c0e9ad8be6b27789039
Hardware Model:      iPad2,2
OS Version:          iPhone OS 6.0.1 (10A523)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Wed Oct 10 23:29:31 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2107.2.34~2/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8940X
Date:                2013-04-27 09:53:43 +0200
Time since snapshot: 152 ms

Free pages:        934
Active pages:      3455
Inactive pages:    1821
Throttled pages:   103117
Purgeable pages:   0
Wired pages:       18795
Largest process:   GreaseBook

Processes
     Name                    <UUID>                       rpages       recent_max       [reason]          (state)

      MobileMail <27df582d2bed3501834661269810ad98>         3928             3928         [vm]         (continuous)
             kbd <24d58ac14ed3340380492fef46eac29d>          574              574         [vm]         (daemon)
            tccd <eb5ddcf533663f8d987d67cae6a4c4ea>          281              281         [vm]         (daemon)
      GreaseBook <2f5df68a7078386298eadbb24ebbdb33>        84210            84210         [vm]         (frontmost) (resume)
            ptpd <0cac6936ffeb362d98eb8073af935d21>          992              992                      (daemon)
    mediaserverd <bdc35c073fe134b9a39b96342a80159e>         1082             1082                      (daemon)
         syslogd <cbef142fa0a839f0885afb693fb169c3>          281              281                      (daemon)
       locationd <4bee615548dd33f48e18bfed4296f05d>         1675             1675                      (daemon)
           wifid <a243b2fcde2537159660b3ee7e809df4>          649              649                      (daemon)
      aosnotifyd <01901b13681f3582b5bfbe53504d08d6>          480              480                      (daemon)
     dataaccessd <117e4e475b14305982f52484564cfbc7>         1319             1319                      (daemon)
   iaptransportd <f784f30dc09d32078d87b450e8113ef6>          241              241                      (daemon)
     SpringBoard <0e3571e8067533e2811a6d444f10a349>         4058             4058                     
      backboardd <a9b5346126a939dfb0920a4bbc48201b>         6057             6057                      (daemon)
         imagent <d15f873abdd233f0a34d77a7d36e9e0f>          329              329                      (daemon)
   mDNSResponder <3e557693f3073697a58da6d27a827d97>          283              283                      (daemon)
  UserEventAgent <6edfd8d8dba23187b05772dcdfc94f90>          589              589                      (daemon)
    syslog_relay <45e9844605d737a08368b5215bb54426>            0                0                      (daemon)
       CVMServer <3ec015e0150d341a929ebbbc45f4c8ac>          104              104                      (daemon)
            afcd <b0aff2e7952e34a9882fec81a8dcdbb2>          165              165                      (daemon)
notification_pro <845b7beebc8538ca9ceef731031983b7>          203              203                      (daemon)
filecoordination <fbab576f37a63b56a1039153fc1aa7d8>          195              195                      (daemon)
       distnoted <a89af76ec8633ac2bbe99bc2b7964bb0>          132              132                      (daemon)
            apsd <d0e432fd45023d629ffb305b7e79d7fb>          403              403                      (daemon)
      aggregated <cd70154f955c31bbab58bf5f0acd3acd>          108              108                      (daemon)
        networkd <b24547cbe04b3e94a4bd406e586cdf8a>          222              222                      (daemon)
        BTServer <f57113a7cc2c33678ee832bc088276be>          356              356                      (daemon)
         configd <4245d73a9e96360399452cf6b8671844>          576              576                      (daemon)
   fairplayd.K94 <1a5f575df8f4368db1eae7ba3da11150>          270              270                      (daemon)
       fseventsd <996cc4ca03793184aea8d781b55bce08>          362              362                      (daemon)
          powerd <2d2ffed5e69638aeba1b92ef124ed861>          198              198                      (daemon)
       securityd <c35e701a5aab3968ae8d93ef8db02e07>          159              159                      (daemon)
       lockdownd <481275a4062931708a7440ff0f73f229>          495              495                      (daemon)
CommCenterClassi <c10fa2a1b7673e1ab14e6ecd11b9b7e7>          557              557                      (daemon)
         notifyd <51c0e03da8a93ac8a595442fcaac531f>          199              199                      (daemon)

**End**
```

Comment: Why are you not saving till the whole download is complete? You should be doing something to move the data to disk rather than being in memory...

Comment: Because I only want to save the data to disk once everything has downloaded.  i.e. I don't want it to save half the data to disk when the other half is still missing.

Comment: Ok, but you need to. At least save to a temporary file and then move the file to its final destination after successful download.

Comment: OK great.  I'm trying that now.  Thanks Wain.  I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: Nope.  Same problem.  I'll use instruments to try and work out where the memory is going.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: After each save (that you should keep small), try resetting the downloading context, otherwise your entire data might still reside in memory. use instruments to track your memory peaks, and use autorelease pools when applicable.

Comment: I believe you need to continually save otherwise how will CD be able to fault objects? After each save you can also manually fault objects that will not be further modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When downloading large data sets into core data, you need to account for lots of things.  When it comes to memory management, the more popular issues are described below.

First and foremost, you need to save frequently, which allows you to purge the memory from the `NSManagedObjectContext` (aka MOC).  At any time, you can see what objects the MOC has, by looking at the `registeredObjects` property of the MOC.

Normally, when you save a MOC, any objects that do not have a strong reference to them are removed from the MOC.  Again, you can check after saving by looking at the `registeredObjects`.  However, if you have relationships in your model, then the objects will contain strong references to each other, which creates a *retain cycle*.  Thus, the objects will never be released until the retain cycle is broken.

You break retain cycles in a MOC by using `refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO`.  You can blow away all objects by calling `reset` but that is rather draconian, and you need to make sure you do not hold any references to managed objects when you do that.

Even if you don't have retain cycles between your managed objects, you could still be inadvertently retaining objects that you will never use again.  This is where, even though you are using ARC, you still need to understand some memory management rules.  Specifically, auto released objects.  They will get automatically released, but not until the autorelease pool reclaims objects.

Thus, you should wrap your operations in your own autorelease pool.  This is very simple:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // Unless you hold references elsewhere, objects allocated in here will be
    // auto released when this scope ends.
}
```

If you have a thread doing your downloading, and you use a MOC of `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, the block you pass to `performBlock` gets automatically wrapped in an autorelease pool.

Comment: Firstly, this is a fantastic answer.  Thanks Jody.  I have a lot of relationships in the data, so I've implementing the 'save' and 'refreshObject' calls after I've updated an objects.  I've also put a release pool around each level of the upgrade.  However, it doesn't make any difference to the 'registeredObjects' count.  If I print the object before the release and after, it's obvious that it's become a fault, but neither the number of registered objects drops, nor does the memory.  Any ideas?

Comment: OK I got it.  I had Undo enabled on the context.  It'm not getting the crash anymore, although memory footprint is still getting pretty big.  Thanks so much Jody!